How to Set Up a Nexus 3 Repository for Alpine Linux's APK Package Manager?
I am working with a Docker image based on Alpine Linux (specifically alpine:latest), and I need to install the curl package using the Alpine Package Keeper (apk). However, I have a Nexus repository and want to source the curl package from there.
Currently, I am unsure how to set up my Nexus 3 repository to function as an APK repository. I have read that a file named APKINDEX.tar.gz is required in the repository, and from what I understand, there isn't a direct way to access Nexus 3 repositories via the command line; only the web interface is available.
Could someone guide me on:

How to properly initialize a Nexus 3 repository to serve as an APK repository?
How to retrieve and install packages from that repository using apk add?

Any help or resources on this setup would be greatly appreciated!
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM <ip-address>:<port>/alpine/git:latest
RUN echo "https://my-nexus-repo/alpine-proxy/v3.10/main > /etc/apk/repositories"
ARG CURL_VERSION=x.xx.0-rx
RUN apk update 
RUN apk add curl=CURL_VERSION

